# Retrieve a document from elastic search by matching two fields

Tags: elasticsearch

My data are stored in elastic search as shown below

```
{  
   "identifier":{  
      "source":"source 1",
      "id":"22081070"
   },
   "title":"Book 1",
   "published":2011,
   "types":[  
      "type1",
      "type2, 
      "type3"
   ]
}
```

Is there a way to retrieve a document with specific "identifier.id" and "identifier.source" parameters? For example I am retrieving the above document with its id as an input with the following:

```
QueryBuilder queryBuilder = QueryBuilders.matchQuery("identifier.id", "22081070");
SearchResponse searchResponse = client.prepareSearch("test-index")
                .setTypes("type").setQuery(queryBuilder).execute().actionGet();
```

but I know know how to add the "identifier.source" as a match parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
BoolQueryBuilder boolQuery = new BoolQueryBuilder();
QueryBuilder queryBuilder1 = QueryBuilders.matchQuery("identifier.id", "22081070");
QueryBuilder queryBuilder2 = QueryBuilders.matchQuery("identifier.source", "source 1");

boolQuery.must(queryBuilder1).must(queryBuilder2);

SearchResponse searchResponse = client.prepareSearch("test-index")
                .setTypes("type").setQuery(boolQuery).execute().actionGet();
```

Comment: Thanks it works, although I have to use termQuery instead of matchQuery. I seems that matchQuery don't work for "identifier.source" property, even though the same analyzer was used for both of them as I can see in _mapping (keyword analyzer). Any thoughts about this issue?

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, what does it mean? Do you get an exception? Error message? If so, what error message?

Comment: It returns zero documents

Comment: Can you post the mapping?

Comment: "identifier":{  
                  "properties":{  
                     "id":{  
                        "type":"string",
                        "index_analyzer":"keyword"
                     },
                     "source":{  
                        "type":"string",
                        "index_analyzer":"keyword"
                     }
                  }
               }

Comment: "term" is "not_analyzed" so, whatever you give it, it will take it as is, no changes. What value did you put in your `termQuery`?

Comment: I use the same values as with matchQuery ie for id: "22081070" and for source: "source 1"

Comment: Here is why the match query returns zero results:
The index_analyzer for "source" is "keyword"; when your example doc is indexed, the "source"field generates the token "source 1". However, there is no search_analyzer specified, so the default for your index is used. If you haven't configured and specified a default, then it is using the standard analyzer, so when you search for "source" = "source 1", the tokens "source" and "1" are emitted. Neither of those are indexed to the document.
The reason the term search *does* work is that a term search does not apply the search analyzer.

Comment: @salvador, whatever @GlenRSmith said :-). Your `source 1` test is analyzed with `match` but `not_analyzed` with `term`, as I mentioned previously.